# How do I set default values to form elements which are created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a SPA using JS and jQuery.
I have created a dynamic form in it in which the user can select to add a particular field. In the final output, those fields which he hasn't generated and used will result as "undefined". Is there any way I can allot a default value to it like an empty string if the user doesn't use it?

I'm attaching a snippet of the html and js code.

```js
var count1 = 1;
var limit1 = 6;

function addInput1(divName) {
    if (count1 == limit1) {
        alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + count1 + " interests");
    } else {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

        newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='myInputs[]' id='int" + (count1 + 1) + "' style='width:100%;' value='' class='text-center' " +
            "placeholder='technology" + (count1 + 1) + "'><br/><br/>";

        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
        count1++;
    }
}
```

```html
 <form class="form1" style="padding-top: 2%;">

  <div class="text-center">

  <h2><b>Full Name</b></h2><br/>
 <input type="text" class="text-center" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Name" style="width:100%;"><br><br/>

 <h2><b>Interested in:</b></h2>
   <div id="dynamicInput1">
   <input type="text" class="text-center" name="interest1" placeholder="technology1" id="int1" style="width:100%;"><br/><br/>
    </div>

  <input type="button" class="btn-primary" value="Add another interest" onClick="addInput1('dynamicInput1');" style="width:auto">
    </div>
   </form>
```

Once the form values are put in, I use another js to replace the original html file with another html file which has the form values. If the user doesn't generate the text input, it gives undefined as the output in those places. I'm attaching a nippet of that js code as well. I know the obvious part that it's coming as undefined because it's undefined but is there a way to put a default value in it like an empty string?

```js
 var experiment1 = function() 
            {
var fullname = $("#fullname").val(); 
              
 var int1 = $("#int1").val();
 var int2 = $("#int2").val();
 var int3 = $("#int3").val();
 var int4 = $("#int4").val();
 var int5 = $("#int5").val();
 var int6 = $("#int6").val();
 '<div class="container">' +
   '<div class="row">' +
   '<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">' +
   '<h3>Interested in</h3>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9">' +
  '<ul class="pull-left" style="font-size:1.4em; padding-top:3%; list-style:none; margin-left:-4%; word-break:normal;">' +
   '<li class="pull-left">' + int1 + '&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</li>' +
   '<li class="pull-left">' + int2 + '&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</li>' +
   '<li class="pull-left">' + int3 + '&#160;&#160;</li><br/>' +
   '<li class="pull-left">' + int4 + '&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</li>' +
    '<li class="pull-left">' + int5 + '&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</li>' +
'<li class="pull-left">' + int6 + '&#160;&#160;</li><br/>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +

            }

        //passing the value to the main html file

        $("#bodytag").html(experiment1);
```

Comment: While `experiment1` is a function, you should be doing `$("#bodytag").html(experiment1())` to put the value it returns into `innerHTML` of `#bodytag`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

You can do a conditional check to see if the value is undefined, for example:

```
var int1 = $("#int1").val();
if (typeof int1 === "undefined") {
     int1 = "";
}
```